# How give access to socket for guest without auth?

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io, jwt

I have chat on React and use socket.io-jwt for auth (https://github.com/auth0-community/auth0-socketio-jwt) on server.

The problem is that I cannot provide guest access to the server and I cannot upload messages to the chat until the user is logged in.

Comment: Hi there, have you found the solution?